# Robust standard errors for poisson/negbin panel data estimators

Tags: r, panel-data, plm, standard-error

I am trying to calculate robust and clustered standard errors for Poisson and Negative Binomial panel data estimators. I am using 'pglm' package.

Ideally, I would be able to use the `coeftest` command from the 'lmtest' package to calculate these SE. However, `coeftest` does not support **pglm** objects.

Here is an example of the model I am trying to calculate.

```r
model1 <- pglm(incidents ~ treatmentdummy + 
       poverty + rural + 
       offset(log(population)), 
       index=c("id","year"), effect= "twoways", 
       model="within", family= "negbin", 
       data=data1)
```

I think that my problem could be solved by any of the three following ways:

1. Transform **pglm** objects into **plm** objects. Then, I would be able to run `coeftest` command.
2. Find a way to run panel data estimations with **plm**.
3. Find another package that imitates `coeftest` command but supports **pglm** objects.

Keep in mind that I am also incorporating fixed effects in my model. Any solution should also be able to support that.

Comment: How many clusters do you have?

Comment: over 2400 clusters

Comment: You could consider to cluster-bootstrap the standard errors.

Comment: This is largely unclear to me. `lmtest::coeftest` does not calculate specific standard errors itself. One can plug-in other standard errors (or more precisely: a variance-covariance matrix or a funtion to compute one) and have the result displayed. That is somewhat the typical way it is done in R (see, e.g., for other function but likewise where you would replace `summary` with `lmtest::coeftest` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71787457/4640346).